# How do I identify or know which control is being referenced in a method?

Tags: iphone

In my specific case, how do I identify or know which UITextField is being referenced in shouldChangeCharactersInRange method?

I know the parameter (UITextField*)textField contains the object being referenced, but how do I compare to identify which one it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you create your interface using IB then you can create `IBOutlet` in your controller for each UI element, connect then in IB and later compare `textField` parameters with them:

   ```
   //header
   IBOutlet UITextField* nameField;
   IBOutlet UITextField* addressField;

   //Implementation
   ...
   if (textField == nameField){
   }
   if (textField == addressField){
   }
   ```

2  In IB you can also assign a unique tag value for each `UITextField` (available for each UIView subclasses) and compare tag values:

```
    #define nameTag 10
    #define addressTag 11

    //Implementation
    ...
    if (textField.tag == nameTag){
    }
    if (textField.tag == addressTag){
    }
```

Comment: Bah you beat me to it again Vladimir :)

Comment: Ah I forgot about tags, but I wanted a better way to do it.  I didn't realize I could just compare the reference name.  Thank you Vladimir.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution is to use tags from interface builder / storyboard, assign tags for each of the text fields.

Then use a switch(textfield.tag) case in your code, code looks much cleaner compared to putting a lot of if statements